# L2TP/IPSec VPN configuration for Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop

Tags: vpn, ipsec

My first question here, and I hope someone can help me out.

I manage an Astaro/Sophos ASG220 UTM9 fw 9.106-17, and I have an L2TP\IPSec VPN object configured using a pre-shared key for authentication.  This works fine for Windows computers, but I need a solution for Ubuntu Desktop 13.10.

Could someone, who has been through this issue with success, please tell me which packages I would need to install on the Ubuntu client and how to configure any conf files involved, so I can connect successfully?

Thanks in advance for your help.